# calculated cost not equal to tensorflow's loss value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've created a simple gradient-descent scenario in order to better understand tensorflow. When I run it though, and use the "guesses" to calculate the loss value manually, I don't get the same value as tensorflow spits out, and I don't understand why.

The program that I've written uses gradient-descent to work out the result of the matrix operation `f(X*A) * B` where `f()` is the sigmoid function, where `X` (1xn) is a placeholder / input value and `A` (nxn) and `B` (nx1) are matrices that need to be discovered. The values for `A` and `B` are populated at the start with linearly increasing values. For a start, I just set `n` to 2.

Here is the test program that illustrates the problem:

```
n = 2
A_actual = numpy.linspace(0, 1, n**2).reshape(n, n)
B_actual = numpy.linspace(0, 1, n).reshape(n, 1)

A = tensorflow.Variable(tensorflow.ones((n, n)), name='A')
B = tensorflow.Variable(tensorflow.ones((n, 1)), name='B')

X = tensorflow.placeholder("float", shape=[1, n], name='X')
y = tensorflow.placeholder("float", name='y')

y_hat = tensorflow.matmul(tensorflow.nn.sigmoid(tensorflow.matmul(X, A)), B)

loss = tensorflow.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y, predictions=y_hat)
cost = tensorflow.reduce_mean(loss)
updates = tensorflow.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)
with tensorflow.Session() as sess:
    init = tensorflow.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(1, 10):
        train_X = numpy.random.rand(n).reshape(1, n)

        h = numpy.matmul(train_X, A_actual)
        train_y = numpy.matmul(h / (numpy.exp(-h) + 1), B_actual)

        _, c = sess.run([updates, loss], {X: train_X, y: train_y })

        A_guess = A.eval()
        B_guess = B.eval()

        # work out the expected loss:
        h_guess = numpy.matmul(train_X, A_guess)

        train_y = numpy.matmul(h / (numpy.exp(-h) + 1), B_actual)
        y_hat = numpy.matmul(h_guess / (numpy.exp(-h_guess) + 1), B_guess)

        expected_cost = (train_y - y_hat)**2

        print "A={}, B={}, train_X = {}, c={}, expected_c={}".format(A_guess, B_guess, train_X, c, expected_cost)
```

At every epoch, I would expect the values of `c` and `expected_c` to match, but they don't. Here's the output for a couple of epochs:

```
A=[[0.99831355 0.99831355]
 [0.9978205  0.9978205 ]], B=[[0.9855833]
 [0.9855833]], train_X = [[0.43161333 0.55779766]], c=0.977798759937, expected_c=[[0.90071899]]
A=[[0.99674106 0.99674106]
 [0.99594545 0.99594545]], B=[[0.97247064]
 [0.97247064]], train_X = [[0.75101306 0.89550778]], c=0.612140238285, expected_c=[[3.25077074]]
A=[[0.9963331 0.9963331]
 [0.9934323 0.9934323]], B=[[0.9615876]
 [0.9615876]], train_X = [[0.15488769 0.95426499]], c=0.524783551693, expected_c=[[0.73085703]]
A=[[0.99290335 0.99290335]
 [0.9930714  0.9930714 ]], B=[[0.9457934]
 [0.9457934]], train_X = [[0.7305608  0.07687351]], c=1.30655503273, expected_c=[[0.74179058]]
A=[[0.9906516 0.9906516]
 [0.9914385 0.9914385]], B=[[0.93114746]
 [0.93114746]], train_X = [[0.74625195 0.54115622]], c=0.876540482044, expected_c=[[1.72666188]]
A=[[0.9897084 0.9897084]
 [0.9894199 0.9894199]], B=[[0.91981167]
 [0.91981167]], train_X = [[0.39296997 0.84106038]], c=0.538159787655, expected_c=[[1.05986646]]
A=[[0.9873394 0.9873394]
 [0.9880559 0.9880559]], B=[[0.9053085]
 [0.9053085]], train_X = [[0.7454906  0.42922246]], c=0.906145870686, expected_c=[[1.32207708]]
A=[[0.98699   0.98699  ]
 [0.9865663 0.9865663]], B=[[0.89463204]
 [0.89463204]], train_X = [[0.0955704 0.4074265]], c=0.737196862698, expected_c=[[0.08112794]]
A=[[0.9847778 0.9847778]
 [0.9857968 0.9857968]], B=[[0.88113374]
 [0.88113374]], train_X = [[0.5787612  0.20131812]], c=0.975076794624, expected_c=[[0.47560335]]
```

There doesn't seem to be any relationship between `c` and `expected_c`, yet I've double-checked my cost calculation (with reference to the [tf.sigmoid](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sigmoid) and [tf.losses.mean_squared_error](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/mean_squared_error) pages) and I can't find any differences.

Why are these not coming out as the same values?

(Note that I'm not yet concerned about the fact that my guesses do not appear to be converging, I'll worry about that once I understand the cost function!)

Comment: It might be that the TF loss is computed _before_ the parameter update whereas your "expected" loss is computed with the values after the update. Can you decouple running `updates` and `loss` and check again?

Comment: @xdurch0 I tried replacing `[updates, loss]` with just `loss` (ie. just skipping the updates altogether) and the cost values still differ wildly (but the weights don't update) so I don't think this is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `xdurch0` correctly pointed out, the `loss` parameter is calculated as part of the evaluation of the graph, so the update occurs *after* that calculation.

To fix it I replaced this line:

```
_, c = sess.run([updates, loss], {X: train_X, y: train_y })
```

With this line:

```
sess.run(updates, {X: train_X, y: train_y })
c = sess.run(loss, {X: train_X, y: train_y })
```

This causes `loss` to be evaluated twice - once for the `updates` call, and again once the gradient descent has been applied.